# Hightchart plot vertical line dynamic

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create vertical red line on the already created graph, but it should compare the date on the x-axis to create line code.

```
plotLines: [{
    color: '#FF0000',
    width: 2,
    value: Date.UTC(2012, 08, 18)
}]
```

Нere is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/neetu/5vfdrhmp/

Thank you

Comment: OK, so what's the actual question? Which date does it need to use? What part are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup you need to use a value that refers to the position of the date in the category array. 
For example to place the line in the middle of 2013 Q2 then use 16.5 - because the 2013 Q2 category is the 16th item in the category and you can then use a decimal to position it exactly.

```
plotLines: [{
    color: '#FF0000',
    width: 2,
    value: 16.5
}]
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vfdrhmp/1/)

This will require a certain amount of math though to determine where on the axis the line should fall...